# assigning numbers entered in a row to an array 3 6 23 12 4 a[0]=3 a[1]=6 a[2]=23 a[3]=12 a[4]=10

Tags: c#, arrays

```
        string[] n = Console.ReadLine().Split();
                
        for (int i = 1; i <6; i++)
        {
            int[] a = long.Parse(n[i]);
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

If each number in a row separated with whitespace - you can use your `Split` more efficiently:

```
int[] array = Console.ReadLine().Split().Select(int.Parse).ToArray(); // Improved according to @Caius Jard comment
```

If need array of `long`s - replace `int.Parse` with `long.Parse` and declare variable as `long[] array`.

You need to add `using System.Linq` to get access to `ToArray` extension method.

**EDIT.**

Insprired by **@Caius Jard**, non-LINQ version:

```
// Read input line and split it by whitespace (default)
string[] values = Console.ReadLine().Split();
 
// Declare arrays for Int or Long values.
// Arrays sizes equals to size of array of input values      
int[] arrayOfInts = new int[values.Length];
long[] arrayOfLongs = new long[values.Length];
       
// Iterate with for loop over amount of input values.     
for (int i = 0; i < values.Length; i++)
{
    // Convert trimmed input value to Int32
    arrayOfInts[i] = int.Parse(values[i].Trim());
    // Or to Int64
    arrayOfLongs[i] = long.Parse(values[i].Trim());
}
```

`int.Parse` and `long.Parse` may be replaced with `Convert.ToInt32` and `Convert.ToInt64` if needed.

Comment: `Split().Select(int.Parse)` will be fine, though overall LINQ probably not for the Programming 101 that this is homework for

Answer (score 0):

Please, don't use *magic constants*: `i < 6`. Here `6` doesn't necessary equal to `n.Length`.
You can put it as

```
    string[] n = Console.ReadLine().Split();

    List<int> list = new List<int>();

    for (int i = 0; i < n.Length; ++i) {
      if (int.TryParse(n[i], out int value))
        list.Add(value); 
      else {
        // Invalid item within user input, say "bla-bla-bla"
        //TODO: either reject the input or ignore the item (here we ignore) 
      } 
    }

    if (list.Count == a.Length) { 
      // We have exactly a.Length - 6 valid integer items
      for (int i = 0; i < a.Length; ++i)
        a[i] = list[i];
    } 
    else { 
      //TODO: erroneous input: we have too few or too many items
    }
```

Comment: thank you bro do you have telegram or facebook